# How to handle index that doesnt exist

Tags: java, netbeans

I am attempting to parse a string of numbers to use in a function.

```
List<Long> longNumbers = List.of(s.split(", ")).stream()
.map(num -> Long.parseLong(num))
.collect(toList());


long nr1 = longNumbers.get(0);
long nr2 = longNumbers.get(1);
long nr3 = longNumbers.get(2);

vaccinationService.VacById(nr1, nr2, nr3)
```

However some of the string variables do not contain exactly 3 numbers, such as "6, 1". How can I get my code to handle this problem? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just iterate over the elements you have and print those (`for(Long n : longNumbers)`). If you need the indices iterate from 0 to `longNumbers.size()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `nr3` is an optional value and the list doesn't always have 3 elements, we need to check the size of the list before retrieving the element on index 2 like this:

```
long nr1 = longNumbers.get(0);
long nr2 = longNumbers.get(1);
long nr3;
if(longNumbers.size()>=3){
    nr3= longNumbers.get(2);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to use these numbers in a follow up function how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: How does the function head look like?

Comment: I have edited the question now to show you

Comment: If you have only two numbers you want `nr3` to be null?

Comment: Yes sometimes it is 3 numbers, sometimes it is two numbers. So when the string entered only has two numbers, how can I handle nr3?

Comment: I edited my answer since the size of your list doenst seem to be dynamic and only holds 2 to 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid runtime crash, utilize [Try..Catch](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp).

So basically simple modification of your code:

```
try{
List<Long> longNumbers = List.of(s.split(", ")).stream()
.map(num -> Long.parseLong(num))
.collect(toList());


long nr1 = longNumbers.get(0);
long nr2 = longNumbers.get(1);
long nr3 = longNumbers.get(2);

vaccinationService.VacById(nr1, nr2, nr3)
}catch(Exeception e){
  System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
  //Also you can handle condition of what to do when the above fails. e.g:
  gotoFunctionToDisplayNumbersWereWrong();

}
```

Combine with [Madlemon's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66547560/12966786) for calling the relevant function from the distinct numbers size got (2 or 3 you state is your case) should be the most optimum solution.